pregunta sobre php y mysql
estoy aprendiendo php y ahora estoy practicando en un sistema de login necesito mostrar si una cuenta esta bloqueada o esta activa
si esta activa en la base de datos muestra como 0 pero si esta bloqueado aparece como 1
les comparto parte del código para que puedan ayudarme , estuve buscando tutoriales pero ninguno aclara la duda que tengo , gracias de antemano.


$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from account where username=\"$_SESSION[user]\" ");
if(! $result) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($conweb));
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $user_vp=$row["vp"];
    $user_dp=$row["dp"];
    $user_mail=$row["email"];
    $user_locked=$row["locked"];
    $user_pass=$row["v"];
    
}
                            
$cont2='
                            <p style="clear: both;"></p>
<table class="table myaccount-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Estado de Cuenta:</td>
            <td><span class="label label-default">Activada</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nombre de usuario:</td>
            <td>'. $_SESSION['user'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>




Pero, ¿cuál es el problema o error exactamente? No estás haciendo ninguna verificación basada en $user_locked, que es la variable donde supongo tienes el estado de la cuenta. Prueba a poner algo como esto: echo ($user_locked == 0) ? 'Activa' : 'Bloqueada'; Cuando pruebas que funciona, podrás hacer una asignación y usarla en el td donde quieres mostrar el estado de la cuenta... Por otra parte, si el usuario es único, no hace falta el while y convendría que pongas un LIMIT 1 a la consulta SQL en ese caso.

Muchas gracias , la verdad estaba intentando buscar ese tipo info , una vez más muchas gracias :)

No estás haciendo ninguna verificación basada en $user_locked, que es la variable donde supongo tienes el estado de la cuenta.
Por otra parte, si el usuario es único, como parece ser, porque muestras los datos fuera del while, entonces no hace falta el while y convendría que pongas un LIMIT 1 a la consulta SQL en ese caso.
Veamos:
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from account where username=\"$_SESSION[user]\" LIMIT 1");
if(! $result) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($conweb));
}

# Si se espera una sola fila no necesitas while
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row) {
    $user_vp=$row["vp"];
    $user_dp=$row["dp"];
    $user_mail=$row["email"];
    $user_locked=$row["locked"];
    $user_pass=$row["v"];

    # Asignamos $status según el valor de $user_locked
    $status=($user_locked == 0) ? 'Activa' : 'Bloqueada';

    # Usamos sprintf, poniendo marcadores %s
    # para mejor claridad del código y control de errores
    $html=sprintf('<p style="clear: both;"></p>
        <table class="table myaccount-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Estado de Cuenta:</td>
              <td><span class="label label-default">%s</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Nombre de usuario:</td>
              <td>%s</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>',
        $status,$_SESSION['user']);
} else {
    $html = "<p>No se encontraron datos</p>";
}
echo $html;

